# Retrieval of page from disk on page fault

Tags: memory, memory-management, x86, cpu-architecture

When a page miss occurs in the main memory, the particular page is then retrieved from the disk. 
My question to the community, how is the memory in the disk indexed with the 32-bit physical address we have after the translation?

Comment: Depends on the OS. You could just use the formula `Disk block = Page Number * (Page Size / Block Size)` and then read `Page Size / Block Size` disk blocks from there.

Comment: Can you take one example and elaborate?

Comment: On a page miss the page table entry does not contain a physical address. Typically the OS is able to use all the bits in the PTE except those indicating an invalid PTE, allowing the OS to have a pointer to a data structure of arbitrary size (probably aligned so that the full address space can be used even though one or perhaps a few bits are used to indicate an invalid PTE).

Comment: Let's fill the formula with concrete values: the disk block size is commonly 512 bytes (on modern HDDs sometimes 4096 bytes). Let's assume a single-level paging mechanism with 32-bit virtual addresses, where 12 bits constitute the offset (the page size is 4096 bytes then) and 20 bits make the index into the page table. Let `256` be the page table index. Result: `Disk block = 256 * (4096 / 512) = 1024`.

Comment: As @PaulA.Clayton pointed, your page got swapped out probably because it couldn't fit in physical memory, therefore it no longer has a physical address, only a virtual one.

Comment: @cad we have located the disk block, we still have to locate the particular 4 kB page that has to be moved to the memory. Can you please also indicate how the 4 kb page is indexed in the particular block?

Comment: The disk block at the index we calculated is equivalent to the location of the page on disk. Now just read `4096 / 512 = 8` of these blocks and you have your page.

Comment: Paul's comment is the answer to your question.